# What actually goes in Oracle when we use setFetchSize on Statement in OJDBC?

Tags: sql, oracle, ojdbc

I need to work with some legacy code where OJDBC is being used. A query is made from the Web and using servlet we have to search and show at max 1000 rows that satisfy the criteria. So a max of 1000 rows are being returned in a specific sort order irrespective of the number of actual rows in the DB. This is being done by setting the fetchSize on the statement being executed.I read that fetchSize is just a hint to DB and it might return more than these number of rows also. This might be the reason i think because of which a break is used in the legacy code while iterating the result set once the count crosses 1000.

Now this functionality needs to be updated to have pagination. I am aware of doing pagination by using ROWNUM as described in [AskTom's](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) article.

But as part of this activity i also need to verify and prove that performance is not being affected. For this i want to know what actually happens in the back-end (Oracle) when fetchSize is set from OJDBC and executed. Is it possible to translate this OJDBC into exact query that can be run directly to check the performance? If fetchSize doesn't guarantee that only the specified number of rows are returned, does it return all the rows that satisfy the criteria?

Thanks for the help.